# Why is a categorical product in Top uniquely equal to the product topology?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

My question is NOT “why does the product topology satisfy the conditions of a categorical product in **Top**”.

Rather, my question is, why does it do so uniquely? I don’t require necessarily a fully rigorous proof, but an conceptual understanding.

My guess is: If we take the cartesian product between two topological spaces $X,Y$, but we endow this product with a trivial topology $\{\emptyset, X\times Y\}$, then this also satisfies the categorical product conditions:
For any topological space $Z$ and continuous functions $f:Z\to X, g:Z\to Y$, there is a unique function $h=f\times g:Z\to X\times Y$. **We don’t need to put any more conditions on the topology of $X\times Y$ for $h$ to be unique.** (This is essentially because the cartesian product $X\times Y$ is already “set-theoretically restricted” enough to ensure uniqueness of $h$). Therefore, we can put **any** topology on $X\times Y$, so long as it makes $h$ unique for all such $(Z,f,g)$. One topology that does this is the product topology, but another one that does it is the topology $\{\emptyset,X\times Y \}$.

**What’s wrong with my argument?**

EDIT: I Immediately realized that while this topology gets you a continuous $h$, it doesn’t get you continuous projections $\pi_X,\pi_Y$...

Comment: So basically you answered the question yourself. So what else do you need?

Comment: @freakish, yes you’re right, lol. What should I do? Delete the question? What’s the standard practice?

Comment: I guess deleting the question is fine.

Comment: The general answer is that products are always determined up to isomorphism in their category.

Comment: @user56834 I think you should leave your question: It serves to be here when others encounter similar issues. Deleting it would not yield future benefits.

Comment: More generally, limits are unique up to isomorphism, where they exist, and the product is an example of a limit. I second @MusaAl-hassy: you shouldn't delete the question, as it may be useful when others search similar questions. Instead, you can add an answer yourself to this!